# List of all of the activities in our application that are running on the device

Tags: android, activity-manager

How to get the list of all activities in our application that are running on the device.

For example: pdf generation and email activities included.

I can check for activities with the code like:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

     // get the info from the currently running task

     List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

     Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::"

             + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());

     ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;

   componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

This will however give information about the running activity which is the top activity.

My idea is to **whitelist** the activities running so that my third party application can run it while on the device. So I basically need all of the running activities in the application.

Comment: Are you looking purely for a coding solution or perhaps would a 3rd party application do the trick?

Comment: In that case, this sounds promising http://www.activity-logger.com/features-android.html

Comment: Do I need to install it on my android device in which my application is running ?

Comment: This required exe file but my application is android app which is .apk file.

Comment: I haven't read the documentation but I would assume it must be a file you run on your PC while debugging your Android app.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

This is the way to get all the running activities in the application -

```
try {
    ActivityInfo[] list = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).activities;

        for(int i = 0;i< list.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("List of running activities"+list[i].name);

        } 
    }

    catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This appears to list all the activities in the currently-running application, NOT on the device

Comment: This lists all activities in app's Manifest when I run it, not only all running activities.

Comment: that sems to be the wrong answer because the Doc says: Array of all <activity> tags included under <application>, or null if there were none. This is only filled in if the flag GET_ACTIVITIES was set.

Comment: This is a wrong as it returns list of all the activities

Answer (score 0):

I've found AppLifecycleHandler as documented in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background/13809991#13809991) to be a great solution for knowing what's happening. I use it primarily to just keep count and clean up when the user is done using the app, but you can implement it with an array in which you store all running activities so you can always call in to find out what's running.