# Challenging behaviour when my app is resumed - how to check on status of other activities in your app?

Tags: android, android-activity

So I have an application which has two activities.

The app opens in the first activity and the user triggers a button which brings a second activity to the foreground. This all works wonderfully well--Until the user suspends the app using the home button when the secondary activity is in the foreground, and then switches back to the app a few moments later.

At this point the primary activity seems to be dead.... This is evidenced because the secondary activity has some transparent elements and you can no longer see the primary activity under it.

To make this more complicated... I can't reproduce this problem. I've tried the same model phone and android version and this behavior doesn't occur for me, its only one user.

Is there a way I can inspect the stack of activities or history, but for my app ONLY and then if the primary app is non existent, take some corrective action?

Edit, I know see that my question was very poorly phrased.

This code kind of does what I want in that it lists my app's activities:
[List of all of the activities in our application that are running on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486672/list-of-all-of-the-activities-running-on-the-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First- for reproduce memory cleaning while your app is in background use [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autokiller) app for purging memory

Second- if your second activity depend on the ui of the first activity maybe you should consider using fragments instead of activities.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment.  I found the other solution with just looking through the application activity stack worked better though.